# How to import a large data set into MongoDB?

Tags: json, mongodb, mongoimport, database

I would like to import a large data set (over 1GB) into MongoDB. The data is provided in Mongo's JSONlike format.

My question is two parts:

1. To import the raw data into Mongodb, is this command the best approach, or is something else preferable? 
   `$ mongoimport  --file dataset name --jsonArray`
2. After importing the data into mongodb, how do I search the a collection for records that certain keywords.

The data I am using can be found [here](https://www.yelp.com/dataset_challenge/dataset)

Thank you!

Comment: Why don't you just download it through your browser first, then import it into mongo?

Comment: oh sorry sir I'll modify question but can you answer my secon dpart? the import

Comment: Are you doing this on computer that you have GUI access to (i.e. a laptop) or on a remote machine?

Comment: Oh sory sir i'm doing in it on ubuntu my windows

Comment: If my answer worked for you, could you upvote it?

Comment: @DanGreen-Leipciger hey sir I have a new question, can you help me answer it also can you please answer me if you have time?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**For Importing the Data**

I would recommend managing your Mongo server via Studio 3T (formerly Mongo Chef), and using their GUI tools to import the data. If you are using a remote machine, you will need to setup your server for remote access.

**For searching for a key term**

This example will return all reviews that contain the text "good" or "enjoy":

```
db.yelp_academic_dataset_review.find({
  $or: [{
    "text": /.*enjoy.*/i
  }, {
    "text": /.*good.*/i
  }]
})
```